# Not getting $fbme['email'] in the facebook $fbme object

Tags: php, facebook

I want to get the facebook $fbme email information using the facebook php SDK.I am getting rest of the information like Firstname,Lastname,Gender but not getting the Email.I have even tried giving the Extended email permissions but that did not help.Please help as soon as possible.

Here is my code

```
         /*
         * Sign up procees for facebook login
         */
        if (array_key_exists("facebook", $_GET)) {


            /*
             * Distroy all sesion data
             */
            $this->objSession->unsetAll();

            /*
             * Distroy all api session data
             */
            $this->objAPISession->unsetAll();



            /*
             * if seesion data is not present then facebook login
             */
            if (0 == $this->objSession->USRlKey) {
                try {
                    include_once "library/facebook/facebook.php";
                } catch (Exception $strError) {
                    echo "facebook.php File not found on server";
                }

                $arrConfigSetting['appid' ]  = FACEBOOK_API_ID;
                $arrConfigSetting['secret']  = FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY;

                $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                      'appId'  => $arrConfigSetting['appid'],
                      'secret' => $arrConfigSetting['secret'],
                      'cookie' => true ,
                    )); 

               $strFacebookUser_id = $facebook->getUser();

                $fbme = null;

                if ($strFacebookUser_id) {
                    try {
                        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
                        $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');

                        if ('' != $fbme['id']) {

                            $this->objAPISession->arrAPIUser['intUsrID'] = $fbme['id'];
                            $this->objAPISession->arrAPIUser['strFirstName'] = isset($fbme['first_name']) ? $fbme['first_name'] : "";
                            $this->objAPISession->arrAPIUser['strLastName'] = isset($fbme['last_name']) ? $fbme['first_name'] : "";
                            $this->objAPISession->arrAPIUser['intUserType'] = 3;
                            $this->objAPISession->arrAPIUser['strSignUpType'] = "Facebook";

                                   $this->_redirect('/login/emailaddress');
                             die;
                        }

                    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                        echo $e;
                    }
                } else {

                    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('next' => "http://www.mywebsite.com/facebooklogin_success", 'req_perms' => 'email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'));
                    //echo("<br>login url=".$loginUrl);
                    return $this->_redirect($loginUrl);
                    //return $this->_redirect('login/index');
                }   




            } else {
                return $this->_redirect('myprofile/index');
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using version 3 of the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) which supports the new OAuth authentication.

Also with version 3 this line should be:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' => "http://dev.popsip.com/facebooklogin_success", 'scope' => 'email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'));
```